# @ViewChild on hidden form returns undefined - How to access it so I can set a focus

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-forms

I have a form which is only visible when a button is clicked. I want the user to click the button and have the focus placed on the first input field once the form is displayed.

Using @Viewchild I can't do this because the form is not available when the component first loads. I get the error `Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of undefined`

**TS**

```
formLoaded = false;

@ViewChild("firstName") nameField: ElementRef;
editName(): void {
 this.formLoaded = true;
 this.nameField.nativeElement.focus();
}
```

**HTML**

```
<button mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="editName()">Edit</button>
 <div *ngIf="formLoaded" class="group">
  <mat-form-field>
   <input #firstName matInput>
  </mat-form-field>
</div>
```

How can I access the input #firstName so I can give it focus?

A simplified version of my actual code is [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/form-focus-5ajd5j?file=src/app/app.component.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make use of the [AfterViewChecked](https://angular.io/api/core/AfterViewChecked) lifecycle hook, it is run everytime change detection is triggered. Thereby, only after the form is present on the template will you set focus for it.

```
ngAfterViewChecked() {
   if (this.formLoaded) {
      this.nameField.nativeElement.focus();
   }
}
```

Remove the focus statement from the *editName* method:

```
@ViewChild("firstName") nameField: ElementRef;
editName(): void {
   this.formLoaded = true;
}
```

Comment: Yes, I got it working with a combination of ngAfterViewChecked and a setTimeout. Without the Timeout I was getting 'ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError' I also changed the static to false as the second argument of the @Viewchild.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the focus method isnide settimeout like this:

```
 editName(): void {
        this.formLoaded = true;
        setTimeout(()=>{
          this.nameField.nativeElement.focus();
        })
     }
```

Another way is to use setter

```
@ViewChild("firstName",{read:MatInput}) set viewC(nameField: MatInput){
 if(nameField){
    nameField.focus();
 }
};
```

[Forked Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/form-focus-rzg2wr?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: This works in the stackblitz but that is a simplified version of my code. In my actual code setting a timeout to any length of time still returns the same error.

Comment: Since you are placing template ref on matInput it might refer matinput reference try to set the viewchild explicitly to refer element like this @ViewChild("firstName",{read:ElementRef}) nameField: ElementRef;

Comment: Still no joy I am afraid, even with a 10 second delay. I have a large form of user info and I am creating a new user with the button click. This triggers an *ngIf and shows the blank form. It seems viewChild never finds the input with #firstName.

Comment: If you console what is it printing on console?

Comment: @ViewChild("firstName",{read:MatInput}) nameField: MatInput;another way is to get matInput instance and utlize matinput focus method, can you try this ?

Comment: Then inside editForm method call like this: this.nameField.focus();

Comment: Still gives an error. Cannot read property 'focus' of undefined. Console also says undefined when I log nameField after the click.

Comment: Another way would be using setter along with viewchild @ViewChild("firstName",{read:MatInput}) set viewC(nameField: MatInput){
 if(nameField){
    nameField.focus();
 }
  console.log(nameField);
};

Comment: and i am not sure why even with settimeout it is throwing error

Comment: Chellappan Thanks for all  your efforts on this. I followed a different answer and it is now working, however I had static set to true as the second argument of @Viewchild when I changed it to false it started working. I also needed a timeout. With these maybe your method would have also worked. I can not unfortunately accept two answers.